# Do not display registration form to logged in users

Tags: php

I'm trying to figure out a way to add if condition to the registration form. Presently logged in users can access the registration form, which isn't right. Below is the piece of code.

Note, my CMS is Wordpress.

I've tried using the:

```
if (is_user_logged_in()) 

/* MAIN CODE HERE */

    else
        return "You are already logged in!";
```

But it only ends up displaying the 'if (is_user...' above the registration form.

Here's the code:

```
<?php
if ('wwm-register.php' == basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']))
     die ('<h2>Direct File Access Prohibited</h2>');


function wwm_register_page() {
global $wpdb, $user_ID;
?>
FUNCTION TO DISPLAY PLANS</div>
<?php
return;
exit;
}

        if (get_option('wwm_form_validator')) {
?>
            FORM VALIDATION SCRIPT
<?php
        }

    $main_fields=get_option('wwm_main_fields');

    $use_plugin_as=get_option('use_plugin_as');

    if ($use_plugin_as!=='all')  {
        if($use_plugin_as=='membership') {
            $type='membership';
            $main_fields[0][show]='1'; //show username and pass and mail
        }elseif($use_plugin_as=='order'){
            $type='order';
            $main_fields[0][show]='0'; //don't show username and pass and mail
        }else{
            $type='membership';
        }
    }


    if (isset($_GET['type'])) {
        if($_GET['type']=='membership') {
            $type='membership';
            $main_fields[0][show]='1'; //show username and pass and mail
        }elseif($_GET['type']=='order'){
            $type='order';
            $main_fields[0][show]='0'; //don't show username and pass and mail
        }
    }



    if ($type)
        $planlist = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT id,title,price,description FROM ".WWM_PLANS_TABLE." WHERE display='1' AND plantype='".$type."'");
    else
        $planlist = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT id,title,price,description FROM ".WWM_PLANS_TABLE." WHERE display='1'");

    if (isset($_POST['preview'])) $preview=$_POST['preview']; else $preview=0;

    if (isset($_POST['username'])) $username=attribute_escape(strip_tags(stripslashes(strtolower(trim($_POST['username'])))));elseif (isset($_GET['username'])) $username=attribute_escape(strip_tags(stripslashes(strtolower(trim($_GET['username'])))));

    if (isset($_POST['pass'])) $pass=attribute_escape(strip_tags(stripslashes((trim($_POST['pass'])))));
    if (isset($_POST['pass2'])) $pass2=attribute_escape(strip_tags(stripslashes((trim($_POST['pass2'])))));

    if (isset($_POST['email'])) $email=attribute_escape(strip_tags(stripslashes((trim($_POST['email'])))));elseif (isset($_GET['email'])) $email=attribute_escape(strip_tags(stripslashes(strtolower(trim($_GET['email'])))));

    if (isset($_POST['companyname'])) $companyname=attribute_escape(strip_tags(stripslashes((trim($_POST['companyname'])))));

    if (isset($_POST['fname'])) $fname=attribute_escape(strip_tags(stripslashes((trim($_POST['fname'])))));elseif (isset($_GET['fname'])) $fname=attribute_escape(strip_tags(stripslashes(strtolower(trim($_GET['fname'])))));

    if (isset($_POST['lname'])) $lname=attribute_escape(strip_tags(stripslashes((trim($_POST['lname'])))));elseif (isset($_GET['lname'])) $lname=attribute_escape(strip_tags(stripslashes(strtolower(trim($_GET['lname'])))));

    if (isset($_POST['nname'])) $nname=attribute_escape(strip_tags(stripslashes((trim($_POST['nname'])))));
    if (isset($_POST['url'])) $url=attribute_escape(strip_tags(stripslashes((trim($_POST['url'])))));elseif (isset($_GET['url'])) $url=attribute_escape(strip_tags(stripslashes(strtolower(trim($_GET['url'])))));

    if (isset($_POST['desc'])) $desc=attribute_escape(strip_tags(stripslashes((trim($_POST['desc'])))));elseif (isset($_GET['desc'])) $desc=attribute_escape(strip_tags(stripslashes(strtolower(trim($_GET['desc'])))));

    if (isset($_POST['yahooim'])) $yahooim=attribute_escape(strip_tags(stripslashes((trim($_POST['yahooim'])))));
    if (isset($_POST['aolim'])) $aolim=attribute_escape(strip_tags(stripslashes((trim($_POST['aolim'])))));
    if (isset($_POST['jabberim'])) $jabberim=attribute_escape(strip_tags(stripslashes((trim($_POST['jabberim'])))));

    if (isset($_POST['countryname'])) $countryname=attribute_escape(strip_tags(stripslashes((trim($_POST['countryname'])))));elseif (isset($_GET['countryname'])) $countryname=attribute_escape(strip_tags(stripslashes(strtolower(trim($_GET['countryname'])))));

    if (isset($_POST['statename'])) $statename=attribute_escape(strip_tags(stripslashes((trim($_POST['statename'])))));
    elseif (isset($_GET['statename'])) $statename=attribute_escape(strip_tags(stripslashes(strtolower(trim($_GET['statename'])))));

    if (isset($_POST['cityname'])) $cityname=attribute_escape(strip_tags(stripslashes((trim($_POST['cityname'])))));
    elseif (isset($_GET['cityname'])) $cityname=attribute_escape(strip_tags(stripslashes(strtolower(trim($_GET['cityname'])))));

    if (isset($_POST['adrs'])) $adrs=attribute_escape(strip_tags(stripslashes((trim($_POST['adrs'])))));
    elseif (isset($_GET['adrs'])) $adrs=attribute_escape(strip_tags(stripslashes(strtolower(trim($_GET['adrs'])))));

    if (isset($_POST['adrs2'])) $adrs2=attribute_escape(strip_tags(stripslashes((trim($_POST['adrs2'])))));
    elseif (isset($_GET['adrs2'])) $adrs2=attribute_escape(strip_tags(stripslashes(strtolower(trim($_GET['adrs2'])))));


    if (isset($_POST['zipcode'])) $zipcode=attribute_escape(strip_tags(stripslashes((trim($_POST['zipcode'])))));
    elseif (isset($_GET['zipcode'])) $zipcode=attribute_escape(strip_tags(stripslashes(strtolower(trim($_GET['zipcode'])))));

    if (isset($_POST['telephone'])) $telephone=attribute_escape(strip_tags(stripslashes((trim($_POST['telephone'])))));
    elseif (isset($_GET['telephone'])) $telephone=attribute_escape(strip_tags(stripslashes(strtolower(trim($_GET['telephone'])))));

    if (isset($_POST['birthday'])) $birthday=attribute_escape(strip_tags(stripslashes((trim($_POST['birthday'])))));
    if (isset($_POST['birthmonth'])) $birthmonth=attribute_escape(strip_tags(stripslashes((trim($_POST['birthmonth'])))));
    if (isset($_POST['birthyear'])) $birthyear=attribute_escape(strip_tags(stripslashes((trim($_POST['birthyear'])))));
    if (isset($_POST['gender'])) $gender=attribute_escape(strip_tags(stripslashes((trim($_POST['gender'])))));
    if (isset($_POST['terms'])) $terms=attribute_escape(strip_tags(stripslashes((trim($_POST['terms'])))));
    if (isset($_POST['avatar'])) $avatar=attribute_escape(strip_tags(stripslashes((trim($_POST['avatar'])))));

    if (isset($_POST['plan'])) $plan=attribute_escape(strip_tags(stripslashes((trim($_POST['plan'])))));elseif (isset($_GET['plan'])) $plan=attribute_escape(strip_tags(stripslashes(strtolower(trim($_GET['plan'])))));

    if (isset($_POST['captcha'])) $captcha=attribute_escape(strip_tags(stripslashes((trim($_POST['captcha'])))));

    if (isset($_POST['promocode'])) $promocode=attribute_escape(strip_tags(stripslashes((trim($_POST['promocode'])))));elseif (isset($_GET['promocode'])) $promocode=attribute_escape(strip_tags(stripslashes(strtolower(trim($_GET['promocode'])))));

    if (isset($_POST['payment_method'])) $payment_method=attribute_escape(strip_tags(stripslashes((trim($_POST['payment_method'])))));elseif (isset($_GET['payment_method'])) $payment_method=attribute_escape(strip_tags(stripslashes(strtolower(trim($_GET['payment_method'])))));

    if (isset($_POST['blog_title'])) $blog_title=attribute_escape(strip_tags(stripslashes((trim($_POST['blog_title'])))));elseif (isset($_GET['blog_title'])) $blog_title=attribute_escape(strip_tags(stripslashes(strtolower(trim($_GET['blog_title'])))));

    if (isset($_POST['blog_domain'])) $blog_domain=attribute_escape(strip_tags(stripslashes((trim($_POST['blog_domain'])))));elseif (isset($_GET['blog_domain'])) $blog_domain=attribute_escape(strip_tags(stripslashes(strtolower(trim($_GET['blog_domain'])))));

    $last_id=wwm_get_fields_last_id('registration');

    for ($i=1;$i<=$last_id;$i++){

        $list=$wpdb->get_row("SELECT label,regex,req FROM ".WWM_FIELDS_TABLE." WHERE id={$i};");
        if ($list) {

            if (isset($_POST['custom-'.$i])) $custom_value[$i]=attribute_escape(stripslashes(strip_tags(trim($_POST['custom-'.$i]))));
            elseif (isset($_GET['custom-'.$i])) $custom_value[$i]=attribute_escape(strip_tags(stripslashes(trim($_GET['custom-'.$i]))));                $custom_regex[$i]=$list->regex;
                    $custom_req[$i]=$list->req;
                    $custom_label[$i]=$list->label; 
                    $custom[$i][label]=$list->label;
                    $custom[$i][value]=$custom_value[$i];

                    if (isset($_POST['file-'.$i])) {
                    $file_custom_fields[]=$_POST['file-'.$i];
                    }

            }

    }

    if (!get_option('wwm_users_can_register')) {
        echo '<div class="wwm-errormessage" >'.__('Registration has been disabled.','wwm').'</div>';
        $hidden=true;   

    }elseif((isset($_GET['action']))){
        $hidden=true;

        if (isset($_GET['method']) && 'twoco'==$_GET['method'])
            include('include/payment_2co.php');
        else
            include('include/payment.php');

    }elseif ( (isset($_GET['mail'])) && (isset($_GET['activate_key'])) ) {
        $hidden=true;
        $user_data = get_user_by_email($_GET['mail']);


        if ( (get_usermeta($user_data->ID,'activate_key')==$_GET['activate_key']) && (get_usermeta($user_data->ID,'status')=='incomplete') ){
            update_usermeta($user_data->ID,'status','0');   
            delete_usermeta($user_data->ID,'activate_key');
            $thanksmsg=__('Your account has been successfully activated.','wwm') . ' <a href="'.wp_login_url().'"> '.__('Log In').'</a>';

            if (get_option('free_members_welcome_mail')) {
                $to=$_GET['mail'];

                $username=$user_data->user_login;
                $fname=$user_data->first_name;
                $lname=$user_data->last_name;
                $expiredate=get_usermeta($user_data->ID,'expire');
                $plan=get_usermeta($user_data->ID,'plan_id');
                    $planinfo=get_plan_info($plan);
                $plantitle=$planinfo->title;


                $blogname=get_option('blogname');
                $subject='Welcome to '.$blogname.'!';

                $body=get_option('free_members_welcome_mail_body');
                $tags=array('{plantitle}','{expiredate}','{firstname}','{lastname}','{username}','{password}','{planid}');
                $replace=array($plantitle,$expiredate,$fname,$lname,$username,$pass,$plan);
                $body=str_replace($tags,$replace,$body);
                $body.='<p>';


                wwm_mail_actions('html'); //set actions

                if ( !wp_mail($to, $subject, $body, $header) ) 
                        $msg= __('The e-mail could not be sent.') . "<br />\n" . __('Possible reason: your host may have disabled the mail() function...') ;
            } //free members welcome

            echo '<div class="wwm-thanksmessage">'.$thanksmsg.'</div>';
        }elseif($user_data->ID && get_usermeta($user_data->ID,'status')!=='incomplete'){
            $errormsg=__('We think you did it before!','wwm');
        echo '<div class="wwm-errormessage" >'.$errormsg.'</div>';
        }elseif((!$user_data->ID) ||get_usermeta($user_data->ID,'activate_key')!==$_GET['activate_key']){
            $errormsg=__('Your activation key is not valid for the plan!','wwm');
            echo '<div class="wwm-errormessage" >'.$errormsg.'</div>';
        }

    }
    elseif ( (isset($_POST['submit'])) || (isset($_POST['submit-upload'])) ) {

        if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['wwm_form_noncename'], plugin_basename(__FILE__) )) 
            return "Invalid nonce. Try agian.";

        require_once(ABSPATH.'/wp-includes/registration.php');
        //require_once(ABSPATH.'/wp-includes/pluggable.php');

        if (isset($_POST['submit-upload'])) { //avatar


        $override['test_form']=false;
        $allowed=array(jpg,jpeg,jpe,gif,png);

        $result=wwm_handle_upload($_FILES['avatarfile'],$override,100,$allowed); //100Kb means max upload size for avatars!

        if (!$result['error']) {
            require_once(ABSPATH.'/wp-admin/includes/image.php');
            $site=get_option(siteurl);
            $path=ABSPATH.'/wp-content/avatar/';
            $urlpath=$site."/wp-content/avatar/";
            if (!is_dir($path))  {
                mkdir($path);//chmod($path,777);
            }
            $avatar_size=get_option('wwm_avatar_width');
            $avatar=wwm_image_resize( $result['file'],$avatar_size, $avatar_size, $crop=false, $suffix=$username.'avatar', $dest_path= $path, $jpeg_quality=75) ;

            if (basename($avatar))
            $avatar=$urlpath.basename($avatar);
            else
            $uploaderror.=$main_fields[20][name].': '.__('Image is very little.','wwm').'.<br/>';

        }else{
            $uploaderror.=$main_fields[20][name].': '.$result['error'].'.<br/>';

        }
    }

    if ($file_custom_fields) {

        foreach($file_custom_fields as $field_id) {

                $override['test_form']=false;
                $allowed=unserialize($wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT options FROM ".WWM_FIELDS_TABLE." WHERE id=%s;",$field_id)));
                $max_upload_size=get_site_option( 'fileupload_maxk', 1500 );
                $result=wwm_handle_upload($_FILES['custom-'.$field_id ],$override,$max_upload_size,$allowed);

                if (!$result['error']) {
                    $custom_value[$field_id]=$result['url'];

                }else{
                    if (!$_FILES['custom-'.$field_id ][error]=='4') { //error[4] means empty file
                        $msgerror.=$custom_label[$field_id].': '.$result['error'].'.<br/>';
                        $custom_value[$field_id]='error';
                    }
                }

        }
    }


    for ($i=1;$i<=$last_id;$i++){
                    if ( ((empty($custom_value[$i])) || ($custom_value[$i]==__('-Select-','wwm'))) && ($custom_req[$i]) ) 
                    $msgerror.= sprintf(__('Please enter %s.', 'wwm'), $custom_label[$i])."<br/>";

    }


    if ( ($planlist) && (strlen($plan)<1) ) $msgerror.=__('Please choose a plan.','wwm').'<br/>';

    if ($main_fields[0][show]) {
        if ((strlen($username)>20) || (strlen($username)<4) ) $msgerror.=__('Please enter a username(at least 4 characters).','wwm').'<br/>';  
        if (username_exists($username)) $msgerror.=sprintf(__('%s already exists.', 'wwm'), $username)."<br/>";
        if (!validate_username($username)) $msgerror.=sprintf(__('%s is not allowed.', 'wwm'), $username)."<br/>";

        if ( (strlen($pass)>30) || (strlen($pass)<6) ) $msgerror.=__('Please enter a password(at least 6 characters).', 'wwm')."<br/>";
        if ( (empty($pass2)) || (strlen($pass2)>30) || ($pass!==$pass2) ) $msgerror.=__('Please re-type password to confirm.', 'wwm')."<br/>";
    }
    if ( ($main_fields[1][show]) || ($main_fields[0][show]) ) {
        if ( ($main_fields[1][req]) && (strlen($email)<6) ) $msgerror.=__('Please enter a correct email address.', 'wwm')."<br/>";

        if ( ($main_fields[1][req]) && (email_exists($email)) && ($type!=='order') ) $msgerror.=__('That email already exists.', 'wwm')."<br/>";
        if ( (!wwm_validate_email($email)) && (!strlen($email)<6) ) $msgerror.=__('Please enter a correct email address.', 'wwm')."<br/>";
    }

        if ( ($main_fields[2][req]) && (strlen($fname)<1) ) $msgerror.=sprintf(__('Please enter %s.', 'wwm'), $main_fields[2][name])."<br/>";
        if ( ($main_fields[3][req]) && (strlen($lname)<1) ) $msgerror.=sprintf(__('Please enter %s.', 'wwm'), $main_fields[3][name])."<br/>";
        if ( (($main_fields[6][req]) && (strlen($url)<10)) || ( (strlen($url)>1) &&
        (!ereg('^(http|https|ftp)\://[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(:[a-zA-Z0-9]*)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9\-\._\?\,\'/\\\+&amp;%\$#\=~])*$',$url) ))) 
        $msgerror.=__('Please enter a correct URL.', 'wwm')."<br/>";
        if ( ($main_fields[4][req]) && (strlen($nname)<5) ) $msgerror.=sprintf(__('Please enter %s.', 'wwm'), $main_fields[4][name])."<br/>";
        if ( ($main_fields[18][req]) && (strlen($desc)<5) ) $msgerror.=sprintf(__('Please enter %s.', 'wwm'), $main_fields[18][name])."<br/>";
        if ( ($main_fields[7][req]) && (strlen($yahooim)<5) ) $msgerror.=sprintf(__('Please enter %s.', 'wwm'), $main_fields[7][name])."<br/>";
        if ( ($main_fields[8][req]) && (strlen($aolim)<5) ) $msgerror.=sprintf(__('Please enter %s.', 'wwm'), $main_fields[8][name])."<br/>";
        if ( ($main_fields[9][req]) && (strlen($jabberim)<5) ) $msgerror.=sprintf(__('Please enter %s.', 'wwm'), $main_fields[9][name])."<br/>";

        if ( ($main_fields[5][req]) && (strlen($companyname)<2) ) $msgerror.=sprintf(__('Please enter %s.', 'wwm'), $main_fields[5][name])."<br/>";

        if ( ($main_fields[12][req]) && (strlen($countryname)<1) ) $msgerror.=__('Please choose your country.', 'wwm')."<br/>";
        if ( ($main_fields[13][req]) && (strlen($statename)<1) ) $msgerror.=sprintf(__('Please enter %s.', 'wwm'), $main_fields[13][name])."<br/>";
        if ( ($main_fields[14][req]) && (strlen($cityname)<1) ) $msgerror.=sprintf(__('Please enter %s.', 'wwm'), $main_fields[14][name])."<br/>";
        if ( ($main_fields[15][req]) && (strlen($adrs)<1) ) $msgerror.=sprintf(__('Please enter %s.', 'wwm'), $main_fields[15][name])."<br/>";
        if ( ($main_fields[16][req]) && (strlen($zipcode)<1)  ) $msgerror.=sprintf(__('Please enter %s.', 'wwm'), $main_fields[16][name])."<br/>";
        if ( ($main_fields[17][req]) && (strlen($telephone)<1) ) $msgerror.=sprintf(__('Please enter %s.', 'wwm'), $main_fields[17][name])."<br/>";
        if ( (($main_fields[10][req]) && (strlen($birthday)<1)) || (($main_fields[10][req]) && (strlen($birthmonth)<1)) || (($main_fields[10][req]) && (strlen($birthyear)<1)) ) $msgerror.=__('Please choose your birthdate.', 'wwm')."<br/>";

        if ( ($main_fields[11][req]) && (strlen($gender)<1) ) $msgerror.=__('Please choose your gender.', 'wwm')."<br/>";
        if ( ($main_fields[19][show]) && (strlen($terms)<1) && ( (!get_option('wwm_show_preview'))||($preview) && (get_option('wwm_show_preview')) ) ) $msgerror.=sprintf(__('Please accept %s.', 'wwm'), $main_fields[19][name])."<br/>";
        if ( ($main_fields[20][req]) && (strlen($avatar)<1) ) $msgerror.=sprintf(__('Please upload a photo as %s.', 'wwm'), $main_fields[20][name])."<br/>";
        if ( ($main_fields[22][req]) && (strlen($promocode)<1) ) $msgerror.=sprintf(__('Please enter %s.', 'wwm'), $main_fields[22][name])."<br/>";

        //if ( ($main_fields[100][show]) && (strlen($blog_domain)<4) ) $msgerror.=sprintf(__('Please enter %s.', 'wwm'), $main_fields[100][name]) . ' '.__('(at least 4 characters)','wwm')." <br/>";
        //if ( ($main_fields[100][show]) && (strlen($blog_title)<4) ) $msgerror.=sprintf(__('Please enter %s.', 'wwm'), $main_fields[101][name]). ' '.__('(at least 4 characters)','wwm')." <br/>";



        if (!get_option('wwm_users_can_register')) $msgerror.=__('Registration has been disabled.', 'wwm')."<br/>";


    if (($main_fields[21][show]) && ( (!get_option('wwm_show_preview'))||($preview) && (get_option('wwm_show_preview')) ) )  {
        $type=get_option('wwm_cap_type');
        if ( $type == 'simple' ){
            if (!class_exists(tam_captcha)) include('captcha/captcha.php');

            $tam_captcha=new tam_captcha;
            $check=$tam_captcha->check(attribute_escape($_POST['captcha-id']), $captcha);

            $tam_captcha->remove(attribute_escape($_POST['captcha-id']));   

            if(!$check){
                $msgerror.=sprintf(__('Please enter a correct %s.', 'wwm'), $main_fields[21][name])."<br/>";

            }   
        } else if ( $type == 'recap'){
            require_once('captcha/recaptchalib.php');
            $privatekey = get_option('wwm_recap_private');
            $recap = rp_recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,

                $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

            if (!$recap->is_valid) {
                $msgerror.=sprintf(__('Please enter a correct %s.', 'wwm'), $main_fields[21][name])."<br/>";

            }
        }
    } //end if requires 



    } //end first if


        if ($_POST['submit']) {
            if ($planlist) {
                $theplan = $wpdb->get_row($wpdb->prepare("SELECT title,price,duration,plantype FROM ".WWM_PLANS_TABLE." WHERE display='1' AND id=%s",$plan) );
                $planprice=$theplan->price;
                $plantitle=$theplan->title;
                $planduration=$theplan->duration;
                $plantype=$theplan->plantype;
            }


            if ( (strstr(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']),'admin.php')) && (is_admin()) ){
                $planprice=0;
                $admin=true; //free for backend page
            }

            if ($promocode) {
                $promocode=strtolower($promocode);
                $codes=get_option('wwm_discount_code');
                $valid=false;
                if ($codes) {
                    for ($id=1;$id<=MAX_DISCOUNT_NUM;$id++ ) {
                        if ($codes[$id][code]==$promocode) {
                            if ( ($codes[$id][plans][0]) && ($codes[$id][plans][0]!==',')) {

                                foreach($codes[$id][plans] as $codeid=>$codeplan) {
                                    if($codeplan==$plan) { 
                                        $planprice=$planprice*((100-$codes[$id][percent])*(1/100));
                                        $valid=true;
                                    }
                                }
                            }else{
                                $valid=true;
                                $planprice=$planprice*((100-$codes[$id][percent])*(1/100));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (!$valid) 
                $msgerror.=sprintf(__('%s is not valid.', 'wwm'), $main_fields[22][name])."<br/>";  
            }

        }   



    if (empty($msgerror) && ($_POST['submit']) ) {

        $user_login = $username;
        $user_email = $email;
        $user_pass = $pass;
        $user_nicename=$nname;
        $user_url=$url;
        $display_name=$user_nicename;
        $first_name=$fname;
        $last_name=$lname;
        $description=$desc;
        //$role=''; leave to default userrole
        //$rich_editing=true;
        $yim=$yahooim;
        $aim=$aolim;
        $jabber=$jabberim;


        if (  ($planprice<=0)&& ($type!='order') && ($plantype!='order') ) {
            $userdata = compact('user_login', 'user_email', 'user_pass','user_nicename','user_url','display_name','first_name','last_name','description','yim','aim','jabber');

            $id=wp_insert_user($userdata);

            update_usermeta($id,'company',$companyname);
            update_usermeta($id,'country',$countryname);
            update_usermeta($id,'state',$statename);
            update_usermeta($id,'city',$cityname);
            update_usermeta($id,'address',$adrs);
            update_usermeta($id,'address2',$adrs2);
            update_usermeta($id,'zip',$zipcode);
            update_usermeta($id,'phone',$telephone);
            if (($birthyear)&&($birthmonth)&&($birthday) ) $birthdate=$birthyear.'-'.$birthmonth.'-'.$birthday.' 00:00:00';
                update_usermeta($id,'birthday',$birthdate);
            update_usermeta($id,'gender',$gender);
            update_usermeta($id,'last_ip', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
            update_usermeta($id,'status','');
            update_usermeta($id,'plan_id',$plan);
            update_usermeta($id,'avatar',$avatar);
            update_usermeta($id,'promocode',$promocode);

                if ($planduration)
                $expiredate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime('+'.$planduration.'day')); else $expiredate=0;

            update_usermeta($id,'expire',$expiredate);

            for ($i=1;$i<=$last_id;$i++) {
                if  ( ($custom_label[$i]) && ($custom_value[$i]) )
                update_usermeta($id,'customfield_'.$i,$custom_value[$i]);
            }

            do_action('wwm_free_member_registered',$id);
```

SEND EMAIL

```
                wwm_mail_actions('html'); //set actions

                if ( !wp_mail($to, $subject, $body, $header) ) 
                        $msg= __('The e-mail could not be sent.') . "<br />\n" . __('Possible reason: your host may have disabled the mail() function...') ;

            } //end verify mail


            $thanksmsg=__('Thank you for your registration.','wwm')."<br/>";
```

/* NOTIFY MEMBERS ON SIGN UP */
                }
            }
        }else{ //else if there is error

```
         if ( ($msgerror)&&(isset($_POST['submit'])) ) echo '<div class="wwm-errormessage" >'.$msgerror.'</div>';   


    if ($uploaderror) echo '<div class="wwm-errormessage" >'.$uploaderror.'</div>'; 

if (!$hidden) { 

    do_action('wwm_register_header');

    ?>

    <div class="wwm_register_page">
```

/*REGISTRATION FORM*/

```
    <?php   

    }//end if
}//end of hidden
}
?>
```

Comment: kinda looks scary with lots of repetitive code

Comment: i would suggest putting all your `if (isset($_POST` inside a `foreach()` to simplify things up, kinda hurts my eyes looking at repetitive code

Comment: Thanks ianace.. Need to clean up the code quite a bit.. not a competent php programmer.. just a beginner

Comment: $data = array(); foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){$data[$key] = $value;} ... this would simplify you'r parsing of the $_POST

Comment: I think i'll have to find a programmer to fix the above codes.. Would you be able to give an estimate on the amount of hours it would take to clean up the if/else conditions and also add the conditional logged in check?

Comment: quite easily done since you are just using the same naming conventions form your $_POST variable for example you could do like this `$data = array(); foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){$data[$key] = attribute_escape(strip_tags(stripslashes((trim($_POST[$key])))));}` and that would simplify things up, but remember to access the `$data[ variable_name ]` because it is placed inside an array

Comment: How do I get in touch with you :)

Comment: So for example $data = array('username','pass','pass2','and more variables'); foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){$data[$key] = attribute_escape(strip_tags(stripslashes((trim($_POST[$key])))));} Would that be the right way?

Comment: with `$data = array(); foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){$data[$key] = attribute_escape(strip_tags(stripslashes((trim($_POST[$key])))));}` the variable names are preserved so you dont have to do ` $data = array('username','pass','pass2','and more variables');`

Comment: I managed to fix the condition. However is there a syntax where I can redirect the user to a certain page? Presently the code is like thisif (is_user_logged_in())   {
   return "You are already logged in!"; 
 }

how to add redirect in the 'return' section

Comment: do you mean an auto redirect or just an `<a>` tag?

Comment: auto redirect.. what i'm trying to do is, instead of showing the message on the registration page, I want to redirect the user to the profile page when they are logged in.

Comment: you could do headers(), just look it up in php.net

Comment: Protip: Try to pare your pasted code to the minimum in order to describe or duplicate your issue.  Dumping all your code into a question is more likely to scare off potential help.  Also, the act of cutting down your code can sometimes help you determine what the actual problem is. I would **strongly** suggest you read [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/asking-better-questions/1228) for hints on how to ask better questions.

Answer (score 0):

You mention:

> But it only ends up displaying the 'if
>   (is_user...' above the registration
>   form.

This indicates that your PHP code is showing up as HTML instead. Make sure you enclose your PHP code properly with the ... tag.

Comment: Hi Extrakun.. I took your advice and put the if(is_user section within the php tags, at the end of the form I did the same for the else condition. Now I get 'Unexpected T_ELSE error.

Comment: Your if...else structure isn't set up properly.

Comment: It goes like this..

<?php if (is_user_logged_in())?>
REGISTRATION FORM
<?php else
  return "You are already logged in!"; ?>

AmI missing something??